# Issue when trying grid system in ionic

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework
I need to get this view done
[image]

I have tried this thing

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-80"> 
          <div class="row">
            <img src="{{jobDetails.category.name}}.png" class="col col-10" width="30">
            <span class="heading col col-10" ng-bind="jobDetails.category.name"></span> 
            (<span ng-bind="jobDetails.subcategory.subCategoryName" class="heading"></span>)
          </div>
       </div> 
   </div>
```

But i am unable to get the correct view there

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I hope to help you with my answer below:

```
 <div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-10">
          <img src="" alt="not available">
        </div>
        <div class="col col-90">
          <span>
            Text goes here
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p>If the text extends in the first row ..</p>
    </div>
```